# Refresh Partial View during async Task

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a script wich is in a ASP.NET MVC5 application. This script is working on 15.000 files so i don't want to wait the end to refresh my view.

My problem is that i would like to refresh my view during my Async task.

I tried many solutions like using AJAX to reload my partial view during my task but when i launch my script, it block evrything and never refresh my view untill the end of this script.

My code :

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ConvertScript";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>ConvertScript</h2>

<div id="PartialDiv">
    @{Html.Partial("getStatus");}
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            setInterval(function () { $('#PartialDiv').load('/Annotation/Refresh'); }, 1000); // every 3 sec
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller

```
 public string testOut(int callDuration, out int threadId)
        {
            var File = from m in db.Annotations where m.IsDocument == true select m;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                Annotation item = File.OrderBy(t => t.FileSize).Skip(i).Take(1).Single();
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\administrator\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Files\\" + item.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(item.DocumentBody);
                    Debug.Write("Doing item nb : " + i + " Filename : " + item.FileName + "\n");
                    stream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
                    stream.Close();
                    Session["count_files"] = (int)Session["count_files"] + 1;
                }
            }
            threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            return ("Yes");
        }

        public delegate string AsyncMethodCaller(int callDuration, out int threadId);

        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 1)]
        public ActionResult Refresh()
        {
            Debug.Write("Refresh " + Session["State"] + "\n");
            if ((int)Session["State"] == 2)
            {
                Debug.Write("In\n");
                int threadId;
                AsyncMethodCaller caller = testOut;
                IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(10, out threadId, null, null);
                string res = caller.EndInvoke(out threadId, result);
            }
            Session["State"] = (int)Session["State"] + 1;
            ViewData["count_file"] = (int)Session["count_files"];
            return PartialView("getStatus");
        }
```

Does anyone have an idea to do that ?

Thanks,
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SignalR to send data to the client from the server in the async method. Basically, SignalR is an implementation by Microsoft of multiple methods (with fallbacks for almost every browser) to allow bi-directionnal communication, which is probably what you are looking for.

I suggest you learn it. You can read about it here : http://signalr.net/, and there is some content about SignalR on [MVA](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/). The documentation is [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr), and it seems to offer a lot of tutorials to get you started. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ! Did you got main tutorial that i can follow on those technologies ? I start with the basic chat on their website but if you have got some other good courses please send me ;) Thanks you !